# Search table by index (choose the index)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, search, indexof

I have created a table where the user should be able to search by name or city.

When searching through names, the function should choose the correct table and the index attached to the call. Here is my attempt.

> **Desired Outcome**: user chooses to search by name or by city and when he/she
>   types in the selected input, the function listens to the index number
>   that is in the call inside the input.

```js
function searchIndex(id, index) {
  // Declare variables
  var filter, tr, td, i;
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var input = document.getElementById(index);
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[''];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}


const searchName = document.getElementById('searchName');
const searchCity = document.getElementById('searchCity');
const Select = document.getElementById('Select');

Select.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (Select.value == 'name') {
    searchName.style.display = 'block';
    searchCity.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    searchName.style.display = 'none';
    searchCity.style.display = 'block';
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}

td {
  width: 250px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="ListDiv">
  <div class="Btns">

    <input id="searchName" onkeyup="searchIndex('List' , [0])" type="text" placeholder="search name" />

    <input id="searchCity" onkeyup="searchIndex('List' , [1])" style="display: none;" type="text" placeholder="search city" />

    <div id="SelectDiv">
      <select id="Select">
            <option value="name">search name</option>
            <option value="city">search city</option>
          </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table id="ListTop">
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>city</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="custScroll">

    <table id="List">
      <tr>
        <td>hanna</td>
        <td>big sandy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bonne</td>
        <td>big sandy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>thomas</td>
        <td>big sandy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "the function listens to the index number that is in the call inside the input" - what does listen to a number mean here? "index attached to the call" - what does attached mean here?

Comment: like onkeyup( 'List' , [0] ) the index is "attached" so it finds the index that is in the function call or "listens" for it

Comment: I think a more helpful description might be: "The user can specify a search term and a table column. When clicking the search button, all table rows (or entries) which contain the search term within the specified column will be highlighted (or whatever)". Instead of "attached" I'd say the column index is supplied as an argument to the `searchIndex` function. Similarly, with "listen to a number" you could e.g. write "receives the column index as the second argument".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, changed the index from `[0]` to `[index]` and added `[index]` into function parameter list.

```js
function searchIndex(id, id2, [index]) {
  // Declare variables
  var filter, tr, td, i;
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var input = document.getElementById(id2);
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[index];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}


const searchName = document.getElementById('searchName');
const searchCity = document.getElementById('searchCity');
const Select = document.getElementById('Select');

Select.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (Select.value == 'name') {
    searchName.style.display = 'block';
    searchCity.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    searchName.style.display = 'none';
    searchCity.style.display = 'block';
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}

td {
  width: 250px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="ListDiv">
  <div class="Btns">

    <input id="searchName" onkeyup="searchIndex('List' , 'searchName', [0])" type="text" placeholder="search name" />

    <input id="searchCity" onkeyup="searchIndex('List' , 'searchCity', [1])" style="display: none;" type="text" placeholder="search city" />

    <div id="SelectDiv">
      <select id="Select">
            <option value="name">search name</option>
            <option value="city">search city</option>
          </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table id="ListTop">
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>city</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="custScroll">

    <table id="List">
      <tr>
        <td>hanna</td>
        <td>big sandy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bonne</td>
        <td>hawkins</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>thomas</td>
        <td>gilmer</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```